# vtd-xml how to move cursor to newly created child

Tags: xml, vtd-xml

I'm trying to modify the xml using VTD-XML but I'm not sure about how I can add a child, then move to that child and add more stuff under it and not have to re-parse every time.

It sounds like I could create the whole structure and just use updateToken to set the xml structure as a text node in the element. 
The problem is that I have many modifications like that that may happen successively and it seems that changes made by XMLModifier are not "real" until you use its output methods. One of them parses and returns a new VTDNav. I feel like that re-parsing after every modification would drastically affect performance.

I'm basically turning xpaths into real structure in cases where they are missing. So I could have an xpath like /root/a where "a" is missing and so I go to /root and create "a". The next path evaluated might have something like /root/a/b and so I need to add "b" as child of "a" and I should be able to move the cursor to the newly added /root/a before adding "b".

I already have this idea working with the default java DOM parser but it is too slow for what I need.

Is there a way to add child elements recursively without having to re-parse while at the same time allowing the newly added elements to be used in subsequent xpath searches?

Comment: That is what I was thinking about doing. The only issue is that I'd have to maintain my own xml like structure that should be able to handle xpaths somewhat so that I may keep adding things that are not fully matched by incoming xpaths and do just one full update of the xml at the end.

Comment: incoming xpaths? or incoming xml?

Comment: it would be a list of xpaths so I meant the next ones that would be evaluated. I believe, however, that I found a way to do  it that wouldn't be as complicated as what I said above. Basically I would just run the xpaths to find the last node that is present for each one of them. If more than one xpath has the same node in comon (as the last present one in the xml), I can then at the end of the whole operation merge their structures before generating the xml that represent the missing portion and then I should be able to add all the changes to the final xml in one go.

Comment: great, do a top level/big picture optimization before diving into details...it is often the simplest thing to help u find the best path forward...